# JPA base64 generator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

How can I define base64 generator for the value based on id?

for example, I have  an entity:

```
@Entity
class Test{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
int id;
//here should be the assigned value encoded to base64 based on id
String value;
}
```

Comment: if you are assigning the generated values then why are you using `GenerationType.AUTO` ?

Comment: I should assign value  to the [String value;] which is based on newly inserted id

Comment: set it in preStore callback?

Comment: you go to Google and search, or you look in the docs of whatever JPA implementation you're using for "Entity Callbacks". And find such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/lifecycle_callbacks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Base64` class, from [Apache commons-codec](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9) bundle, to encode or decode strings .

For more information on `Base64` class , you can refer to [Apache's documentation page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) for `Base64` class.